# How to determine whether $\| \mathbf{X} \mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{A}\|_2^2$ is convex?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have two unknown matrices $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$, and a given matrix $\mathbf{A}$. I performed gradient descent for

$$\text{minimize} \quad \| \mathbf{X} \mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{A}\|_2^2$$

but it doesn't converge to any minima. Is this because the objective function is non-convex if $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are dependent and convex otherwise? Is it right to say?

Comment: What do you mean by "dependent"?  Even for numbers, $(xy - o)^2$ is not a convex function of $(x,y)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I plotted z = $(x \times y - a)^2$ and saw that for $x, y$ in range 0 and 1, the function is convex. I therefore applied gradient descent because I know that the minima exists between 0 and 1. However during the descent, I could not apply this constraint without disturbing the descent.

Comment: If you "saw" that, your eyes deceived you.  The Hessian matrix of $f(x,y) = (xy-a)^2$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ has determinant $-4 (xy-a)(3xy-a)$.  In  order for $f(x,y)$ to be convex we need this determinant nonnegative, which is true (in the case $a > 0$) only if $a/3 \le xy \le a$.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to use the Frobenius norm instead?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I used 2-norm because I could use standard result in matrix-cookbook to get the gradient. Frobenius norm would work for my optimisation as well.

Comment: Are $\rm X, Y$ square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robert explained in the comments, your function is *not* convex. (It is still surprising to me that gradient descent doesn't work (so that your function does not attain its infimum) but off of the top of my head I cannot rule out that this can happen.)

Presumably your $X$ and $Y$ are rectangular (otherwise the minimization is trivial). If you are OK using the Frobenius norm, you can solve the problem directly, without gradient descent, using the truncated SVD: see for instance the explanation [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Low-rank_matrix_approximation).